# Django REST Framework The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.', code='invalid')

Tags: python, django, flutter, api, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to update user's profile image but it doesn't and the serializer doesn't update so when I printed the errors I got that error
`The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.', code='invalid')` and I don't know what I'm doing wrong and Thanks in advance

---

> I'm trying to update it then display the data in my **Flutter** application , don't want it to be displayed in HTML

## **views.py**

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def user_update(request,pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        
        try:
            user_p = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        except:
            user_p = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
        
        serializer1 = UserSerializer(instance = user , data = request.data)

        serializer2 = UserUpdateSerializer(instance = user_p , data = request.data)

        if serializer1.is_valid() and serializer2.is_valid():
            serializer1.save()  #Doesn't Save
            serializer2.save()  #Deosn't Save

        Serializer_list = [serializer1.data, serializer2.data]
        

        return Response(Serializer_list)
```

## **serializers.py**

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email']


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
```

## **models.py**

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user',default='default.png')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300 :
            output_size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

## **Here's the Input**

`Content-Type: application/json`

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "user4",
    "email": "email2@gmail.com",
    "image": "/media/default.png"
}
```

Comment: I printed out the `serializer1.validated_data` and got the data but when I printed out `serializer2.validated_data` I got an empty braces

Comment: I printed the errors using `serializer2.errors` and i got this `The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.`

Comment: I believe the problem is actually in the HTML template for this page, which you haven't shown.  Specifically, the `image` field (which is the only file upload field I see mentioned in your code) - either you have specified inappropriate options for it, or it's not actually a file upload field at all.

Comment: @jasonharper I don't want to display it in html template , I'm trying to update then to display it in my Flutter App

Comment: Well, whatever is generating this POST request, it's doing something wrong related to the `image` field.

Comment: @jasonharper How can I display the image in JSON then so I can do CRUD on

Comment: First of all, I recommend you look into DRF generics. Also, when you upload image you need `multipart/form-data`. I would also assume you don't want to create user if one of the serializers fail, so try and use [atomic transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic).

Comment: @BojanKogoj I will try that and I'll tell if it worked , Thanks !